# Unity Networking error "Disconnecting connId=0 to prevent exploits from an Exception in MessageHandler"

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I am quite new to Unity mirror networking, I got below problem when I click "Host(Server + Client)", some document saying this because of I am not referring to an instance of an object, but where should I make changes? The player controller scripts is copied fromhttps://github.com/janjilecek/unity_tutorial/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs, and the avatar got from ready player me Unity SDK. Appreciate if anyone can give me some explanation on how to solve such issues, thank you.

```
Disconnecting connId=0 to prevent exploits from an Exception in MessageHandler: NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mirror.NetworkIdentity.OnStartServer () [0x00085] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkIdentity.cs:664 
  at Mirror.NetworkServer.SpawnObject (UnityEngine.GameObject obj, Mirror.NetworkConnection ownerConnection) [0x00081] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkServer.cs:1090 
  at Mirror.NetworkServer.Spawn (UnityEngine.GameObject obj, Mirror.NetworkConnection ownerConnection) [0x00000] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkServer.cs:1116 
  at Mirror.NetworkServer.Respawn (Mirror.NetworkIdentity identity) [0x00008] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkServer.cs:1214 
  at Mirror.NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection (Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient conn, UnityEngine.GameObject player) [0x00065] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkServer.cs:765 
  at Mirror.NetworkManager.OnServerAddPlayer (Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient conn) [0x0005b] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkManager.cs:1269 
  at Mirror.NetworkManager.OnServerAddPlayerInternal (Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient conn, Mirror.AddPlayerMessage msg) [0x00060] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkManager.cs:1156 
  at Mirror.MessagePacking+<>c__DisplayClass7_0`2[T,C].<WrapHandler>g__Wrapped|0 (C conn, T msg, System.Int32 _) [0x00000] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\MessagePacking.cs:144 
  at Mirror.MessagePacking+<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2[T,C].<WrapHandler>b__0 (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn, Mirror.NetworkReader reader, System.Int32 channelId) [0x0007a] in C:\Users\Downloads\3d project\Assets\Mirror\Runtime\MessagePacking.cs:126 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Mirror.MessagePacking/<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2<Mirror.AddPlayerMessage, Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient>:<WrapHandler>b__0 (Mirror.NetworkConnection,Mirror.NetworkReader,int) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/MessagePacking.cs:130)
Mirror.NetworkServer:UnpackAndInvoke (Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient,Mirror.NetworkReader,int) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs:470)
Mirror.NetworkServer:OnTransportData (int,System.ArraySegment`1<byte>,int) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs:533)
Mirror.LocalConnectionToServer:Send (System.ArraySegment`1<byte>,int) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/LocalConnectionToServer.cs:45)
Mirror.NetworkConnection:Send<Mirror.AddPlayerMessage> (Mirror.AddPlayerMessage,int) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkConnection.cs:139)
Mirror.NetworkClient:AddPlayer () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:995)
Mirror.NetworkManager:OnClientConnect () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1295)
Mirror.NetworkManager:OnClientConnect (Mirror.NetworkConnection) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1301)
Mirror.NetworkManager:OnClientAuthenticated () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1189)
Mirror.NetworkManager:OnClientConnectInternal () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1171)
Mirror.LocalConnectionToServer:Update () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/LocalConnectionToServer.cs:59)
Mirror.NetworkClient:NetworkLateUpdate () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:1407)
Mirror.NetworkLoop:NetworkLateUpdate () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkLoop.cs:205)
```